# What is the fastest way to ping large list of IP address and generate markers based on result on google map

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to Create a network monitoring sample app where I have a location which can have multiple IP address associated with it, and there can be hundreds of such locations. I want to ping IP addresses for each location and based on ping result I want to create markers on the Google Map.

Right now this is what I do. ( Asp.NET MVC Project ).

I have one controller which returns list of location with IP addresses in json format. See sample json data.

```
{"$id":"25","SiteIpAddresses":[{"$id":"26","Site":{"$ref":"25"},"Id":22,"SiteId":12,"IpAddress":"184.68.22.62","Type":"WAN","SubType":"Ethernet1","CreatedOn":"2015-08-25T11:46:10.013","CreatedBy":"4aafa31e-1174-401e-8742-c074cc2d1027","ModifiedOn":null,"ModifiedBy":null},{"$id":"27","Site":{"$ref":"25"},"Id":23,"SiteId":12,"IpAddress":"10.60.37.1","Type":"LAN","SubType":"IP for Voice","CreatedOn":"2015-08-25T11:47:03.81","CreatedBy":"4aafa31e-1174-401e-8742-c074cc2d1027","ModifiedOn":null,"ModifiedBy":null},{"$id":"28","Site":{"$ref":"25"},"Id":24,"SiteId":12,"IpAddress":"10.60.36.1","Type":"LAN","SubType":"IP for Data","CreatedOn":"2015-08-25T11:48:07.017","CreatedBy":"4aafa31e-1174-401e-8742-c074cc2d1027","ModifiedOn":null,"ModifiedBy":null}],"Id":12,"Name":"Store# 296","Address":"Williams Lake 315G Yorston Street, Williams Lake, BC, V2G 1H1","Latitude":"52.126655","Longitude":"-122.141094","CreatedOn":"2015-08-25T11:43:32.423","CreatedBy":"4aafa31e-1174-401e-8742-c074cc2d1027","ModifiedOn":null,"ModifiedBy":null}
```

After getting this list of locations I iterate through each location and starts ajax call for each location. See the controller method below which basically pings all the IP addresses on that location and returns data using which I can create Marker on google Map.

```
[HttpPost]
        public string PingIP(Site site)
        {
            try
            {
                GoogleMap map = new GoogleMap();
                map.GeoLatitude = site.Longitude;
                map.GeoLongitude = site.Latitude;
                map.PlaceName = site.Name;

                List<string> status = new List<string>();

                foreach (var ipaddress in site.SiteIpAddresses)
                {
                    if (ipaddress.IpAddress != null)
                    {
                        Ping ping = new Ping();
                        PingReply pr = ping.Send(ipaddress.IpAddress);
                        map.PlaceName += "<br/>" + ipaddress.SubType + " : " + ipaddress.IpAddress + " : " + pr.Status;
                        status.Add(pr.Status.ToString());

                    }
                }

                if (status.Count(s => status.Contains("Success")) > (site.SiteIpAddresses.Count / 2))
                {
                    map.MarkerImage = "00E64D";
                }
                else
                {
                    map.MarkerImage = "FD7567";
                }

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(map, Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                });

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

This programming works fine. but it will become slow with hundreds of locations  because for each location it will make AJAX request and on success it will create marker.

Is there any elegant way of pinging large number of IP addresses which is more optimized then the approach that I have implemented?

**Update To Move Calls on Server Side**

```
 public JsonResult GetNetworkMap()
        {
            List<GoogleMap> googleMapData = new List<GoogleMap>();

            StormCloudDbContext ctx = new StormCloudDbContext();
            var data = ctx.Sites.Include("SiteIpAddresses").Where(x => x.SiteIpAddresses.Count > 0).ToList();
            Parallel.ForEach(data, item =>
            {
                GoogleMap map = new GoogleMap();
                map.GeoLatitude = item.Longitude;
                map.GeoLongitude = item.Latitude;
                map.PlaceName = item.Name;

                List<string> status = new List<string>();

                Parallel.ForEach(item.SiteIpAddresses, ipaddress =>
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipaddress.IpAddress))
                    {
                        Ping ping = new Ping();
                        PingReply pr = ping.Send(ipaddress.IpAddress);
                        map.PlaceName += "<br/>" + ipaddress.SubType + " : " + ipaddress.IpAddress + " : " + pr.Status;
                        status.Add(pr.Status.ToString());
                    }
                });

                if (status.Count(s => status.Contains("Success")) > (item.SiteIpAddresses.Count / 2))
                {
                    map.MarkerImage = "00E64D";
                }
                else
                {
                    map.MarkerImage = "FD7567";
                }

                // From here is it possible to raise client side event that will draw marker on google map ? 
                googleMapData.Add(map);
            });
            return Json(googleMapData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I can recommend is to ping IP addresses in parallel. It will be way faster:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ipAddresses, ipAddress => ...)
```

If you need a solid app that pings thousands of IPs you should look into a cloud service that distributes the work between instances. Since you are using Microsoft stack I would recommend you to use Azure cloud for this.

Comment: I am actually making all the call async and partially using ajax requests. Is there any other improvement i can do in this ? Because once all IP addresses are returned i need to notify browser to create the marker

Comment: @SachinTrivedi if you do it via ajax requests you will get performance issues on the client when IPs count is high because your client will be making tones of http requests. I would recommend to move all of this on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks. I had it that way initially. Is it possible to raise kind of event so that when ever IP ping for one location is over it notifies browser to draw a marker on map. ?

Comment: @SachinTrivedi use SignalR for server-to-client acknowledgements.

Comment: Sorry but i am pretty new to signalR. Can you see the updated question and guide me what to do if i want to raise an event at the commented place.

Comment: @SachinTrivedi SignalR is fairly simple. Check this link for instructions http://asp.net/signalr

Comment: Thanks a bunch for suggesting signalR. I have completed this :) will be posting the whole solution as blogpost soon.